# how to use @Table annotation of class org.hibernate.annotations.Table in hibernate

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, annotations

My class name is

> BatchJob

My table name is

> batch_jobs

I am using @Table of the class org.hibernate.annotations.Table instead of javax.persistence

My code of the class BatchJob is

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Table;


@Entity
@Table(appliesTo="batch_jobs")
public class BatchJob {
```

I am getting error

> org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @org.hibernate.annotations.Table
>   references an unknown table: batch_jobs

when I changed the class of the @Entity notation to org.hibernate.annotations

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.Entity;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Table;


@Entity
@Table(appliesTo="batch_jobs")
public class BatchJob {
```

I am getting error

> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: BatchJob is not
>   mapped [From BatchJob]

My query

```
allBatchJobs=session.createQuery("From BatchJob").list();
```

My hibernate.cfg.xml mapping

```
<mapping class="com.company.bmdashboard.beans.BatchJob"></mapping>
```

When I am changing my class name to batch_jobs the code is working fine, but I want to use the name BatchJob and I dont want to use javax.persistence class.

Please guide me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of Hibernate are you using? It could be related to the following issue [HHH-10913](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10913)

Comment: I am using 4.3.11 . I read the link you gave but it didnt give me any solution. Do you have something in mind?

Comment: from that issue seems to me what you are asking isn't feasible, because the appliesTo attribute have to referer to a _already existent_ table, it's not intended to declare the name of the table like you would.

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="batch_jobs")
public class BatchJob {
```

Comment: @Table doesnt have (name=" " ) feature

Answer (score 0):

Please use javax.persistence package like below

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
```

Comment: I dont want to use javax.persistence for @Table.

Answer (score 0):

`@org.hibernate.annotations.Table` use value from `javax.persistence.Table;` and/or from `javax.persistence.SecondaryTables;`. For an example:

```
@Table(name = "batch_jobs")
@SecondaryTables({
        @SecondaryTable(name="batch")
})
@Entity
@org.hibernate.annotations.Table(inverse = true, appliesTo = "batch")
public class BatchJob {
```

So, `@org.hibernate.annotations.Table` is not equal to `javax.persistence.Table;`, this is different annotations with different purpose.